# OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python

Boa tarde,

Estou tentando emular um IBM 3270 utilizando a lib py3270,porém estou tomando erro ao estanciar a classe Emulator desta lib. Alguém faça idéia do que possa ser?

```
from py3270 import Emulator
def connnect():
    em = Emulator(visible=False)
```

Erro:

> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in **init**
>      errread, errwrite)
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1327, in _execute_child
>      raise child_exception
>   OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

Problema resolvido. O erro ocorria pois dentro da classe `Emulator` tinha um `if True e False`, onde um chamava o emulador `x3270` e o outro chamava o emulador `s3270`. Assim, para resolver o problema basta instalar os 2 emuladores.

```
sudo apt-get install x3270
sudo apt-get install s3270
```

Comment: Na verdade parece que o seu problema era exclusivamente de versão incorreta instalada, não?